# Derby, Java EE. Running integration test to file database, does not get dropped

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, derby

How do I configure derby not to drop my database between each unit/integration test ? I want to keep the data between runs.

```
dbDialect=DERBY
XADataSourceClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientXADataSource
databaseName=ForumThreadDB
createDatabase=update
serverName=localhost
portNumber=1527
DriverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ForumThreadDB;create=true
user=APP
password=whatever
```

I just tried to connect to derby outside. It is possible that things are never persisted, although I get no error when persisting, but I remember this have happened before.

I also get this error on startup of the test

> ---> WARN o.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'ForumThreadDomainPU',
>   root URL
>   [file:/C:/Projects/OurForum/ForumThreadDomain/target/classes/].  The
>   error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level
>   to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.

Comment: Do you restart the NetworkServer before each test?

Comment: no, you don't but derby doesn't drop databases even if create="true" is specified(I have the same setup). Which version are you using? Did you try to connect to the Database between test?

Comment: I just tried to connect to derby outside. It is possible that things are never persisted, although I get no error when persisting, but I remember this have happened before. I also get this error on startup of the test::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::---> WARN  o.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'ForumThreadDomainPU', root URL [file:/C:/Projects/OurForum/ForumThreadDomain/target/classes/]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.

Comment: I would try to find out if you don't persist the data, this seems a probable explanation of your problem.

Comment: Perhaps your code sets autocommit=false, and then never issues a commit?

Comment: The database-drop should be the expected behaviour: Each test must run in isolation and shouldn't depend on other test execution

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this could be more to do with the Junit setting 
try adding

```
@Rollback(value=false)
```

before the method for which you don't want the persistence to rollback

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your tests within Maven, you can use a [Maven plugin I wrote for Derby](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin). It starts up an in-memory Derby database for the duration of your tests, so all of them could share the same data.

Check out the [USAGE file here](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin/blob/master/USAGE). The plugin is available via Maven Central so you don't need to add extra repositories.